# Umbraco Contour form answers formatting email

Tags: email, umbraco, crm, contour, umbraco-contour

Umbraco Contour form answers formatting email

When a user fills out an Umbraco Contour Form, the form is submitted to my email address. Is there a way to format the answers using Umbraco, so they can be easily added to client's CRM?

1.) Here is the **current** format in which answers are received:

```
First Name:
John

Email:
johnsmith@email.com

Message: 
Thanks for your help
```

2.) This is what I need it to output via email:

```
>>>FirstName=John<<<

>>>Email=johnsmith@email.com<<<

>>>Message= Thanks for your help<<<
```

Any advice would be really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Contour you are using.

You can use the XSLT Transformed Email workflow to send an email formatted exactly how you want. You just have to upload the XSLT file that does the work. In newer versions of UmbracoForms (as Contour is now called) you can use a Razor view to customise the emails (this was only released this week, so no docs on that yet).

You could also create your own workflow to build the email as well if you wanted.